# List l = new ArrayList<Number>(); The static type of l is List<Number>? What does that mean?

Tags: java

```
List l = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

The static type of l is List?
What does "static type" here mean?
I read it in sun's java tutorials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "static type" of an expression is the type as the *compiler* thinks of it - the compile-time type. This may be different from the *execution-time type* of the *value* of the variable.

For example, consider this:

```
Object obj = "hello";
```

The *compile-time type* (or static type) of the `obj` variable is `java.lang.Object`. At execution time, however, the value of `obj` is a reference to an object of type `java.lang.String`.

Comment: What is the static type of 'l' here and why is it so?

Comment: @Rekha: The static type of `l` is the raw type `List`, because that's how the variable is declared. For variables, the static type is simple - it's just the type the variable is declared to be. Other expressions have static types too though - for example, the static type of a method call is the return type of that method.

Comment: l.add(0, new Integer(42)); The static type second formal parameter of the add method is String.But how? shouldn't it be Object?

Comment: @Rekha: Yes, the static type of the second formal parameter is indeed Object in this case - but only when you're using `l`, the variable of the raw type. Are you sure you're not thinking of `ls` which is a `List<String>` from the other question?